# Display a different image and disable the link once clicked? (Javascript/Ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

The link I'm using is:

```
echo "<br/><div class='right' id='post" . $id . "'>
<img src='/images/like.png' title='Like it?' alt='Like button' 
       onClick='likeButton(" . $id . ");'>( " . getLikes($id) . " )</div><br/>";
```

and the javascript function is:

```
function likeButton(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../likes/" + id, 
        type: "post", 
        data: {
            id: id},
        success: function(likes) {
        $('#post' + id).html(likes);
    }}); 
}
```

it works great - except that when I click, it just gets rid of the link and returns the number. What I'd like it to return is a different link (different image, no onClick):

```
echo "<br/><div class='right' id='post" . $id . "'>
<img src='/images/liked.png' title='Thanks for liking this post!' alt='Like button - liked'>
          ( " . getLikes($id) . " )</div><br/>";
```

Any idea how I could do that?

This is what I have now in PHP, but of course, it only works when I refresh the page, which ruins the entire reason it's using JS...

```
if(isLiked($post->id) == "true") {
    echo "<br/><div class='right' id='post" . $id . "'><img src='/images/liked.png' title='Thanks for liking this post!' alt='Like button - liked'>( " . getLikes($id) . " )</div><br/>";
} else {
    echo "<br/><div class='right' id='post" . $id . "'><img src='/images/like.png' title='Like it?' alt='Like button' onClick='likeButton(" . $id . ");'>( " . getLikes($id) . " )</div><br/>";
}
```